# Could not set Use Local IIS URL Web Server for SharePoint Web Server project in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: debugging, sharepoint, iis, service, web

I have a custom SharePoint ASP.NET Web Service project.
I've setup it to debug as described in http://www.sharepoint-tips.com/2007/08/web-services-on-sharepoint-making-f5.html

it used to work as long as I was working with Visual Studio 2005.
but now I want to setup Visual Studio 2010 environment,
and I'm stuck trying to set 'Use Local IIS Web server' setting in VS, the error says: "The local IIS URL ... specified for web project ... has not been configured."
Tried in both: Windows2003 with MOSS 2007 and Windows 2008 with SharePoint server 2010. All the same.
What I'm missing? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

For Visual Studio 2010 and SharePoint 2010, F5 should work right out of the box. There's no need for any special tricks. Have a try without that outdated blog posting.

Comment: hm, I'm in doubt, how that possible?

Comment: hm, I'm in doubt, how that possible? look, I have to define WEB page of project properties anyway. So, my Start URL is http://server:port/_layouts/MyService.asmx and if I don't use Local IIS, I should leave the 'Use Visual studio development server'. This combination obviously do not allow me to hit a breakpoint.

Comment: @vladimirleontyev try following http://www.thesharepointblog.net/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?List=815f255a%2Dd0ef%2D4258%2Dbe2a%2D28487dc9975c&ID=67 .